# Resistor/Synthetic Load for Caseta Lamp Dimmer

Tags: electrical, led, dimmer-switch

I have a Lutron Caseta Plug-In Lamp Dimmer with a cheap LED light strip plugged into it. It strobes every 10 seconds or so when the dimmer is off. I believe this is due to the "minimum load" problem.

I believe the solution is to add a resistor or some sort of synthetic load. Is there something off the shelf I can use? Most of the bypass/synthetic loads/etc are all for hard wired switches. I'm hoping there's something I can plug in betwen the lamp and the dimmer.

UPDATE: To answer Harper's questions:

- it's not extendable
- it looks like it's two wires down the strip. I think it's cutable
- See the attached picture:

[image: The wall wart and connector]

Thanks!

Comment: What is the internal working voltage of the LED strip? Is it extendable? Cuttable? At what interval?

Comment: If you don't really care about how hacky the solution is, I would try a 330 ohm resistor (or whatever you have) wrapped around the legs of the connector to the low voltage side of that LED powersupply. ( left side of picture ) Be carefull not to short them out or you may have to replace the power supply.

Comment: I don't mind hacky, but I don't know if I trust myself to wrap a resistor and not burn the house down. Are you saying to wrap around the peg on the part with the clear plastic? Or the black power supply? Camera left or stage left? :(

Comment: Plug in an incandescent 5 or 10 Watt night light in the dimmer along side the plug to the lamp. This may stabilize the dimmer. If there is only one plug in the dimmer, then use one of those multi plug adaptors.

Comment: Jim, that worked! I just happened to have a night light kicking around. Works perfectly. The Caseta box has two outlets on it. If you want to post an answer I'll accept it! Thanks!